# Time Machine backup to run my MacBook on another

Tags: time-machine, backup, external-disk

My MacBook is in the shop for repair. I have my Mom's MacBook, but the hard drive has failed. I'm wondering if I can use the time machine backup of my computer via USB to basically run my hard drive on her computer. I can plug my external hard drive in and boot to it, but there are no options to simply run the computer off the external hard drive, like it was my own computer.

Can I tell the computer to just use the external drive with the back up as it's own so I can access my files and programs like it was my own laptop?

Comment: I do not think that would work, since the TM organizes the files differently. Since the hard drive is not working you could use a USB stick with OSX on it and boot from it. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201663